# SSH Agent no longer starting after installing Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, msysgit, ssh-agent

Installed msysGit, wrote the code to start ssh-agent in `.profile`, everything worked.

Installed cygwin, **without Git**, just ssh and cURL.

SSH Agent no longer starting when Git bash opens.

I can start a new ssh-agent process instance, I see it when running `ps` in the Git bash, but when trying to use `ssh-add`, I get this error:
`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`

With cygwin, lots of `.profile` and `.bashrc` files were created in it's install folder (C:\cygwin). Not sure if this is the issue.

How can I fix this, please?

Comment: Could it be a path issue? like a `C:\Cygwin\bin` prepended to your `%PATH%` and masking the original msysgit ssh-add executable?

Comment: Hi VonC. In advanced system settings, Env. Vars, PATH there is no mention of cygwin. Also, running `%path%` in the Run window opens my user folder which contains the `.profile` file with the code to start SSH agent.

Comment: can you double-check that by looking at the full PATH: type in a DOS windows `set PATH`.

Comment: Yup, there's no mention of cygwin there. There is the path to Git's bin folder though.

Comment: Looking at cygwin, I have openssh and libssh2_1 installed.

Comment: Assuming that you can do eval `ssh-agent` ; ssh-add ; then I suspect that your ssh-agent is not called correctly as it is detached from your sessions.  http://kb.iu.edu/data/aeww.html

Comment: I can run them, I see the Agent process ID, ssh-add does not attach to that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at my answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695337/cygwins-ssh-add-returns-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-age) for the `ssh-add` issue.  Hopefully, this solution should work in your scenario too.

Comment: Thanks, SHC. I removed Cygwin to make it work. Yours is a better solution.