# cygwin's ssh-add returns "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Tags: ssh, cygwin, ssh-agent

I have started ssh-agent:

```
$ ssh-agent.exe
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-LagrQoD3JRqg/agent.3600; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=7784; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 7784;
```

Next I try to add a key:

```
$ ssh-add /cygdrive/h/mykey.pem
```

The response I get is:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to run (git/ssh) authentication agent?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4083079/456814).